# how to make textbox content shareable in windows 8 xaml app when user clicks share from charm settings?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, winrt-async

I have one text textbox in my Windows8 Store app (xaml) application and I want to make it shareable when user selects Share option from Charm settings ? Is that possible to in windows 8 store xaml app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to respond to the "DataRequested" event and add the content of the textbox to the data package.  Here is a code sample:

JavaScript:

```
// Call this during initialization
function registerForShare() {
    var dataTransferManager = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataTransferManager.getForCurrentView();
    dataTransferManager.addEventListener("datarequested", shareTextHandler);
}

function shareTextHandler(e) {
    var request = e.request;
    request.data.properties.title = "Your title";
    request.data.properties.description = "Description of what you're sharing";
    request.data.setText(yourTextBox.Text);
}
```

C#:

```
// Call this during initialization
private void ShareSourceLoad()
{
    var dataTransferManager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
    dataTransferManager.DataRequested += DataRequested;
}

private void DataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    DataRequest request = e.Request;
    request.Data.Properties.Title = "Your title";
    request.Data.Properties.Description = "Description of what you're sharing";
    request.Data.SetText(yourTextBox.Text);
}
```